# Show category name, and last 5 post titles below category name?

Tags: categories

Is there a function that will let me display a category title and the last 5 post titles from that category just below it? Is there a loop which can do this and list post titles of that category in an un ordered list with the category title just above outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't stated where the category id will come from, nor how you want to style the category title, and if the post titles are supposed to be linked to the single post; therefore just the basic structure:

```
<?php 
$cat_id = 137; 
    echo '<div class="category-title">'.get_category($cat_id)->name.'</div>;
    $cat_posts = get_posts(array('category__in' => array($cat_id), 'posts_per_page' =>5));
    if($cat_posts) {
        echo '<ul class="category-posts">';
        foreach($cat_posts as $cat_post) {
            echo '<li class="category-post">'.get_the_title($cat_post->ID).'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify where i'd get the cat ID, I figured i'd hard code the category ID as you showed. For styling I can just wrap the echo function in a div and give it a class or ID same with the ul and li tags. Thanks

Comment: answer edited to add a div and some css classes.

Comment: Thanks for making the edits I wouldn't have added them like that